# Closure: ClassCastException java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn

Tags: clojure

I am defining a function "true-or-false" that will take an argument and print "1" if it is true and "0" if it is false but when I run my function with the argument:

```
(= 5 4)
```

it returns the error: "ClassCastException java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn"

Code:

```
(defn true-or-false [x] (if (x)
  (println "1")
  (println "0")))

(def a (= 5 4))

(true-or-false a)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `clojure.lang.IFn` interface provides access to invoking functions, but what you are passing to `true-or-false` appears to be a number. You shouldn't be wrapping `x` in parentheses inside `if` – that would mean you are invoking the `x` function call (see [clojure.org reference](http://clojure.org/reference/special_forms#if) on the `if` special form).